# How can I repair moving square - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to ask you for help. I'm creating a moving square that have to work in this way:

1. I'm grabbing it
2. It follows my cursor
3. It stays in place where I moused up

But I have a problem with the second point because the square is lagging when I'm using offsetX / Y. I discovered that the reason is the cursor on the square, because then the offset stops counting the axes X/Y. What can I do with it? When I move square to left or top, then it's ok.

HTML CODE:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="square">
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: bisque;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 122, 122);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blueviolet;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const square = document.querySelector('.square')
const container = document.querySelector('.container')


square.addEventListener('mousedown', createClass);
square.addEventListener('mouseup', removeClass);
container.addEventListener('mousemove', movingSquare);


// ADDING CLASS 'ACTIVE'
function createClass(e) {
    e.target.className = "square active";
}

// MOVING SQUARE
function movingSquare (e) {

        if (square.classList.contains('active')) {
        square.style.transform = `translate(${e.offsetX}px, ${e.offsetY}px)`;
        // square.style.left = e.offsetX + 'px';
        // square.style.top = e.offsetY + 'px';
    }   
}

// REMOVING CLASS 'ACTIVE'
function removeClass(e) {
    e.target.className = "square"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a possible advantage of of using `.offset` values but I prefer to use `clientX` and `clientY` values. It does require adjustment to allow for the positions of the parent element but is not difficult.

In my snippet, instead of adding and removing classes, I access the `.left` and `.top` style properties of the element. A class name could be added if you want to change other aspects.

Like in your code I use event listeners for `mousedown`, `mousemove`, and `mouseup`.

In the `mousedown` event I set a `boolean` flag `true`  if the target element is the moveable box (this equates to your class addition). I also set `.client` cursor positions for the start, and update the initial `left` and `top` values (relative to its parent container by subtraction) for the moveable element.

This allows the `mousemove` listener to update (provided the target flag was set `true`) the style `left` and `top` properties by an amount equal to the movement of the cursor coordinates since the `mousedown` was made.

```js
const box = document.getElementsByClassName('square')[0];
let downInBox=false; 
let initialLeft = 0;
let initialTop = 0;
let deltaX = 0;
let deltaY = 0;
let startX = 0;
let startY = 0;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
  if (event.target == box ) {
    downInBox=true;
    
    initialLeft = parseInt(box.getBoundingClientRect().left - box.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().left);

    initialTop = parseInt(box.getBoundingClientRect().top - box.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top);

    startX = event.clientX;
    startY = event.clientY;

  } // end if

}); // end mousedown;

document.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
  downInBox=false;
}); // end mouseup;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
  
  if (downInBox) {
  
  deltaX = startX-event.clientX;
  deltaY = startY-event.clientY;
  
  box.style.left =  `${initialLeft-deltaX}px`;
  box.style.top =  `${initialTop-deltaY}px`;
  
  } // end if;

}); // end mousemove;
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: bisque;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}

.container {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 122, 122);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blueviolet;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="square">
        </div>
    </div>
```

The `mouseup` listener simply resets the flag `false` (equivalent to you removing the class).